# .prop('disabled', true); no funciona en funcion Each JS

Tags: javascript, each

Mi idea es para mi formulario recorrer los inputs de tipo number y si el total de estos es superior a la variable `faltan` entonces deshabilitar los inputs que estén a cero. 
Al parecer la función funciona hasta cierto punto, pero cuando se trata de deshabilitar inputs no lo hace....

```js
 let faltan = 5;
        let total = 0;
        $('input[type=number]').change(function() {
            console.log('change');
            $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
                total = parseInt(total) + parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            if (total >= faltan) {
                $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                    console.log('disable');
                    if ($(this).val() === 0) {
                        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('input[type=number]').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="number" id="1" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="2" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="3" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="4" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="5" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="6" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="7" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="8" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="9" value="0"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema esta aca `===`

```
if ($(this).val() === 0) {
```

Tenes que reemplazarlo por `==`

```
if ($(this).val() == 0) {
```

Básicamente `==` hace una conversión de tipos y `===` no lo hace

Tus `$(this).val()` tienen como valor `'0'`

```
   '0' ==  0     :> True
    0  ==  0     :> True
   '0' == '0'   :> True



  '0' ===  0  :> False
  '0' === '0' :> True
   0  ===  0  :> True
```

Comment: Puesto que has sido el primero en responder te doy la respuesta a tí, he cambiado el `=== 0` por `=== '0'` pues necesito que la comprobación sea `===` gracias

Answer (score 2):

Estas muy cerca de lo que quieres.  Te faltan dos cosas:

1. Cambia `===` por `==` cuando chequeas si el valor es igual a 0.
2. Las variables `faltan` y `total` debes de declarlas dentro del `.change()`, de otro modo el calculo es incorrecto.

Algo asi:

```js
        $('input[type=number]').change(function() {
            let faltan = 5;
            let total = 0;
            console.log('change');
            $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
                total = parseInt(total) + parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            if (total >= faltan) {
                $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                    console.log('disable');
                    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('input[type=number]').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="number" id="1" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="2" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="3" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="4" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="5" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="6" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="7" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="8" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="9" value="0"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: En realidad solo el total lo puse dentro, me di cuenta después de escribir la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El valor que quieres darle a la propiedad es `disabled = "disabled"`. Por lo tanto: `.prop("disabled", "disabled")`

Por otro lado, el valor de un input es un string, por lo que `===` no está evaluando bien la condición.

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando:

```js
let faltan = 5;
        let total = 0;
        $('input[type=number]').change(function() {
            console.log('change');
            $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
                total = parseInt(total) + parseInt($(this).val());
                console.log(total);
            });
            if (total >= faltan) {
                $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                    console.log('disable');
                    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                        $(this).prop('disabled', "disabled");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log("enable");
                $('input[type=number]').each(function() {
                  $(this).prop('disabled', false);
                });
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="number" id="1" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="2" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="3" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="4" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="5" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="6" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="7" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="8" value="0"><br>
  <input type="number" id="9" value="0"><br>
</form>
```

Como último comentario, sospecho que la lógica en esta línea no está bien:

```
total = parseInt(total) + parseInt($(this).val());
```

ya que hace que el total siempre aumente, y nunca se vuelven a habilitar los inputs. No sé qué es lo que querés hacer exactamente...

Comment: Además de que total ya es un número, no es necesario hacer la conversión